# How to use tensorflow-cloud with my own python wheel?

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to use tensorflow-cloud to train my model with GCP.
However, our code is quite extensive and runs locally with our custom python package.
I created a custom wheel for that but don't know how to pass it to tensorflow-cloud.

I debugged in the tensorflow-cloud code and found that it creates a tar-file that is copied to the GCP bucket, and then copied into the docker container. I guess I have to add the wheel to the tar file and the reference it in the requirements.txt.

However, the tfc.run does not allows me to pass any additional files for the tar:

```
import tensorflow_cloud as tfc

res = tfc.run(
    requirements_txt="requirements.txt", 
    chief_config=tfc.MachineConfig(
        cpu_cores=8,
        memory=30,
        accelerator_type=tfc.AcceleratorType.NVIDIA_TESLA_T4,
        accelerator_count=2,
   ),
   docker_config=tfc.DockerConfig(image_build_bucket=GCP_BUCKET, 
   parent_image="tensorflow/tensorflow:2.7.0-gpu"),
)
```

Comment: I may have found the answer in github: "Please note that all the files in the same directory tree as entry_point will be packaged in the docker image created, along with the entry_point file. It's recommended to create a new directory to house each cloud project which includes necessary files and nothing else, to optimize image build times."

Comment: Using the entry points put the wheel into the tar and copies it to the bucket, but it is not copied into the docker container, since the Dockerfile does not contain the right "COPY" command. Whats the point that everything is copied into the TAR but not into the container?

Comment: Update: The "COPY" exists but comes after the "pip install" command, so pip does not see the wheel. You may patch tensorflow-cloud: containerize.py, move the lines "lines.append("COPY {} {}".format(self.destination_dir,                                       self.destination_dir))" before the pip call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the files in the same directory tree as entry_point will be packaged in the docker image created, along with the entry_point file.

Using the entry point, it puts the wheel into the tar and copies it to the bucket.

The "COPY" exists but comes after the "pip install" command, so pip does not see the wheel.

You have to patch tensorflow-cloud in containerize.py:

move the lines

```
lines.append("COPY {} {}".format(self.destination_dir, self.destination_dir))
```

before the pip call.